# How to make a nested list to appear like a table with collapsed borders?

Tags: html, css

I have some information with the following semantic structure:

```
Company
    Project 1
        Monday
            Activity 1
            Activity 2
        Tuesday
            Activity 3
        ...
    Project 2
        Day of the week
            Activity 1...n
Company 2
    ...
```

And I chose to use lists in the markup because of how the information is related. However, it has to be laid out to appear like a table for printing purposes. I used flexboxes to make it look like so, the only thing is that I can't make the borders to collapse. I can't use tables because the responsive version does lay the information out like a list, and tables break the semantic structure of the information. So the question is:

How can I make it appear like a table (with collapsed borders)? Or is there a better solution for this?

This is how the markup looks:

```
<ul class="container">
  <li class="company-item">
    Company
    <ul class="projects-container">

      <li class="project-item">
        Project 1
        <ul class="days-container">
          <li class="day-item">Monday
            <ul class="activities-container">
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="day-item">Saturday
            <ul class="activities-container">
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="project-item">
        Project 2
        <ul class="days-container">
          <li class="day-item">Monday
            <ul class="activities-container">
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="day-item">Saturday
            <ul class="activities-container">
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS rules I used to lay it out like a table:

```
/* resest for this example */

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* using flex */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.projects-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.days-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.activities-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.project-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.day-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.activity-item {
  padding: 10pt;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTUn8/23/). Don't mind the layout at the activities level.

Comment: It's hard to tell without having the current styling.  Could you post your markup and CSS as well?

Answer (score 1):

Done. I found out that there's not a simple way to do this, instead, the solution was to *fiddle* with the border rules for each element and changing a couple things on the markup, like surrounding the "headers" with spans with a block display. Here's the final markup:

```
<ul id="container">
  <li class="company-item">
    <span class="company-title">Company</span>
    <ul class="projects-container">

      <li class="project-item">
        <span class="project-title">Project 1</span>
        <ul class="days-container">
          <li class="day-item">
            <span class="day-title">Monday</span>
            <ul class="activities-container">
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="day-item">
            <span class="day-title">Saturday</span>
            <ul class="activities-container">
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="project-item">
        <span class="project-title">Project 2</span>
        <ul class="days-container">
          <li class="day-item">
            <span class="day-title">Monday</span>
            <ul class="activities-container">
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="day-item">
            <span class="day-title">Saturday</span>
            <ul class="activities-container">
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
              <li class="activity-item">Activities</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the final CSS:

```
/* resest for this example */

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 0;
}

span {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
}


/* using flex */

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-width: 0 0 1pt 0;
}

.company-item {
  border-width: 1pt 0 1pt 1pt;
}

.company-title {
  display: block;
  border-width: 0 1pt 0 0;
}

.projects-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.project-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-width: 1pt 0 0 0;
}

.project-title {
  display: block;
  border-width: 0 1pt 0 0;
}

.days-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.day-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-width: 1pt 1pt 0 0;
}

.day-title {
  display: block;
  border-width: 0 0 1pt 0;
}

.activities-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.activity-item {
  padding: 10pt;
}

.activity-item:not(:last-child) {
  border-width: 0 0 1pt 0;
}
```

[Here's the final jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTUn8/26/).